# Are bijective morphisms of varieties homeomorphisms?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Every topologist knows that a continuous bijection does not need to be a homeomorphism. I was just realizing that I don't know examples of this happening for varieties (irreducible, reduced and separated schemes of finite type over a field, preferably algebraically closed) with the Zariski topology. I know bijections which are not isomorphisms of varieties, like the normalisation of a cuspidal curve $\tilde C \to C$, but this is still a homeomorphism on the underlying sets (because Zariski topology for curves is just complements of finite sets).

So my question is: Is every bijective morphism of varieties $X \to Y$ a homeomorphism?

Comment: Sorry by bijective do you mean on the $\overline k$-points?

Comment: @KentaS I meant on the underlying topological space of the scheme, thought of as a locally ringed space. Is that equivalent to being bijective on $\bar k$-points? Clearly bijective on $k$-points is not enough, as witnessed by the map $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb R[x,y] / (x^2+y^2) \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb R, (x,y) \mapsto 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't $\mathbb G_m\sqcup\{0\}\to\mathbb A^1$ work? (the image of the open subset $\{0\}\subset \mathbb G_m\sqcup\{0\}$ is not open.)

Comment: Well, the left hand side is not irreducible (I should have clarified my definition of variety...)

Comment: Sorry yes if irreducibility is required this is not an example.

Answer (score 0):

Take a normalization of a nodal curve and remove one of the preimages of the node. The resulting morphism is a bijection which is not a homeomorphism.

However, every bijection is an isomorphism (not just a homeomorphism) [once you require the target to be normal.](https://mathoverflow.net/q/264204/131868)

Comment: That is a homeomorphism, since the Zariski topology on both curves is just the cofinite topology (plus a generic point). Maybe if you take a product with another (smooth) curve, so that the Zariski topology becomes more interesting?

Comment: A minor modification of this example works. Let $X = \mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$, let $Y$ be the scheme obtained from $\mathbb{A}^2$ by gluing the point $(0,0)$ with the point $(1,0)$ and let $X \to Y$ be the natural morphism. Then the preimage of the line $x = 0$ is closed in $X$, but its image in $Y$ is not.

Comment: @red_trumpet Right, sorry, I thought of the analytic topology for some reason.